# how to change only the body text

Tags: html, wordpress, css, text

In my single wordpress posts I want to apply a padding of 100px to the left and right text.  The problem is that when I apply it to .single .post-content the images also get a padding. However, I want all of the images on the posts pages to be set to 100%. Is there a way to separate the actual body text and the images? This seems like a fairly simple question. But I can't figure it out. Any help is appreciated.

single.php

```html
<?php
get_header();
if (have_posts()) :
while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<article class="post">
    
    
        <?php $featuredImage = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'full' ); ?>
<div class="banner" style="background:url(<?php echo $featuredImage; ?>) no-repeat;"></div>
    
    
    
<?php wpb_set_post_views(get_the_ID()); ?>    
    <div class="post-info">    
    <h1 class="post-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
   <h2 class="post-date"><?php echo strip_tags(get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'location', 'Location: ', ', ', ' • ' ));?><?php the_date('F m, Y'); ?></h2>

    </div>
    <div class="post-content"><?php the_content(); ?></div>
    <div id="wrapper-footer"><div class="post-footer"><h1 class="post-footer-comment"><?php comments_popup_link ('No Comments', '1 Comment', '% Comments', 'post-footer-comment-count', 'none'); ?></h1><div class="share"><span>share</span> <?php get_template_part( 'share-buttons-post' ); ?></div></div>
        <div class="post-footer-bloglovin"><h1>never miss a post</h1><h2><a href="#">follow on email'</a></h2></div></div>
 <?php get_template_part( 'prevandnextpost' ); ?>
     <?php get_template_part( 'related-posts' ); ?>

<?php comments_template(); ?>
</article>
<?php endwhile;
else :
echo '<p>No content found</p>';
endif;
get_footer();
 
?>
```

css

```html
.single .post-title,
.post-title a,
.post-title a:link, .post-title a:visited {
  font-family: 'Questrial', sans-serif;
    font-size:30px;
    margin-left:6px;
margin: 0 auto;
    color:#000000;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
margin-top:30px;
}
.single .post-date {
    font-family: 'Questrial', sans-serif;
    font-size:13px;
    margin-left:6px;
margin: 0 auto;
    color:#000000;
}  
.single .post-content  {
        text-decoration: none;
    color: #000000;
   display: block;
    font-family: 'Crimson Text', serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin:0 auto;
    margin-top: -50px;
    padding-left:100px;
    padding-right:100px;
}
.single .post-info {
background:#ffffff;
padding-left: 100px;
    padding-right:100px;
       max-width: 1865px;
    background-position:center;
    background-clip: content-box;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height:110px;
    bottom:100px;
    position: relative;
}
.single img {
    max-width:100%;
    padding: 0 0 0 0 !important;
    height:auto;
}
```

Comment: Could you add a link to the page?

Comment: Its on a local host.

Comment: Upload to live test server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding the padding to this selector (which searches for `.post-content` inside of `.single` element):

```
.single .post-content
```

Try wrapping text inside a `p` tag:

```
.post-content p {
    padding-left:100px;
    padding-right:100px;
}
```

Example below:

```css
.post-content {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000000;
  display: block;
  font-family: 'Crimson Text', serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 0px;
  /* padding-left: 100px; */
  /* padding-right: 100px; */
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
.post-content p {
  padding-left: 100px;
  padding-right: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="post-content">
  <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=300×100&w=300&h=100" />
  <p>TEST CONTENT TEST CONTENT OTHER TEST CONTENT TEST LONGER WORD</p>
</div>
```

Comment: With this code it will add the padding to the text. But it just slides the images to the left, so now there is a padding of 200 on the right side of the images.

Comment: The image is inside or outside of post-content?

Comment: The images inside the post content.

Comment: Yes since it was pushing it to the left it was likely. So the thing is, that padding we are adding is also the container where the image is (.post-content) there it pushes it. Can you wrap the text inside a <p> tag or add a class to just the text inside .post-content to best isolate it from image?

Comment: I edited the example based on your edit and comments.

Comment: Unfortunately, even if you wrap the text inside a <p> tag it still affects the images.  So even though there is padding on the text, there is also padding on the images.

Comment: If you are impacting the `p` tag only then there is something else pushing it, you can see that working on the snippet, image is isolated fine from `p` 's padding.

Comment: I did some searching and found out wordpress puts a p tag around images too. So I just added a function to remove the p tag from the images and now everything works perfectly. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Great! yea adding tags is typical wordpress hehe :)

Answer (score 0):

if you defined:

```
.single .post-content  {
    ...
    padding-left:100px;
    padding-right:100px;
}
```

and images are inside of `.post-content`, then you need to state a following rule:

```
.single img  {
    max-width:100%;
    padding: 0 0 0 0 !important;
    height:auto;
    margin-left: -100px;
    margin-right: -100px;
}
```

Comment: I think it is because of .styled `.single img {...}' - try to add negative margins here

Comment: I've changed answer.